# Calculating the distance between 2 sets of lat/long coordinates with Pandas and Geopy

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I am trying to use 2 different dataframes each with a different set of lat/long coordinates to calculate the distance between them using Geopy.

```
from geopy import distance

def dist_calc (row):
    start = (row['Lat_1' ], row['Long_1'])
    stop = (row['Lat_2'], row['Long_2'])
    return distance.great_circle(start, stop).km

df['distance'] = df.apply (lambda row: dist_calc (row), axis=1)
```

I keep getting the below error.
I have tried with , ignore_index=True as well.

```
KeyError: ('Lat_2', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Do I need to do merge or concatenate my dataframes to complete this operation? Or how do I make this code work?

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Oh I understand that the code is not working as it is only calling on dataframe number 1.

Comment: Pardon? Also, can you share all relevant code and data? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat your dfs and then run your function:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

def dist_calc (row):
    start = (row['Lat_1' ], row['Long_1'])
    stop = (row['Lat_2'], row['Long_2'])
    return distance.great_circle(start, stop).km

new_df['distance'] = new_df.apply (lambda row: dist_calc (row), axis=1)
```